# How to speed up iPhone game application?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, drawing, cgcontext

I am developing iPhone game application using one UIView and GraphicsContext. The belows are what I am doing:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 480));
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

drawing with contextRef:

```
UIImage* imageContext = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

... call [self setNeedsDisplayInRect];

(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        [imageContext drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        // it takes a lot time (about 0.120 seconds) to draw imageContext on iPhone 4 device....
}
```

The problem is that drawing imageContext takes a lot time. It takes about 0.12 or more sec. On iPhone device, drawing image takes much time. So, I am looking for a solution to solve the problem or drawing images in less time.

Does anyone know how to reduce the time?
How to develop a game on iPhone? In App Store, there are a lot games. Every game has proper speed.

Please recommend me the method or example of developing a game with one UIView.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, I agree with Bonegh and lm2s below, that you should consider using a game engine for your game, as they are better both in APIs and performance for the things games need to be able to do.  That said, I'm wondering why you're drawing into a graphics context outside of drawRect:.  Normally you should just do your drawing in drawRect: inside the graphics context that will already be set up for you there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a framework, cocos2d is one of the best and most used on the iphone for 2d games. There is also Unity, and a few other 3d frameworks, if your using UIView and CGContextRef i'm guessing your making a 2d game.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org

This framework uses OpenGLES to render sprites, it comes with 2 different physics engines to use (i prefer box2d) and has a very busy and useful community to get help from.

Good luck!

Comment: There's also the Sparrow 2d engine (http://www.sparrow-framework.org/) which "they" say is easy to understand and work with.

Comment: having used both i'd still recommend cocos2d purely for the fact that you get both box2d and chipmunk physics engines with it, a bustling community, a plethora of tutorials to be found on google as well as tonnes of downloadable tools to help you create your game. e.g. Zwoptex, Particle Creator, LevelSVG, Inkscape, fully commented example files.